# What is the proper way to pass data between two view controllers inside a NSSplitViewController?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Overview: My app structure looks like this:

```
NSSplitViewController
`- SidebarViewController
|  `- NSOutlineViewController
|     `- NSTreeController
|       `- SidebarEntity (static)
`- ContentViewController
   `- NSTableViewController
      `- NSArrayController
         `- ContentEntity (CoreData)
```

Task: I would like to filter `ContentEntity` list based on selection in the sidebar.

Problem: I have no idea what is the proper way to pass selection changes over from `SidebarVC` to `ContentVC`.

Environment: XCode 8.2.1, Swift 3, OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing through Cocoa related books I've found the solution that is considered the "proper" one. I sould create a `SidebarVCDelegate` protocol with proper method for receiving sidebar selection change, make proper filtering method inside `ContentVC`, and make the `NSSplitController` a delegate for the Sidebar, filtering the result set based upon the call from delegate.

Comment: Any chance you could post a simple example of this? Thanks. :)