# How can I pass data between multiple split view controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, splitview

I have a window that has a vertical split view controller. The left side has a horizontal split view controller inside. The top left part is the map, where I want to pass the data from the right side of the window (marked red) to set variables in the map's viewController. How can I do it?

[image: Window image here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to pass data between two view controllers inside a NSSplitViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727151/what-is-the-proper-way-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers-inside-a-nsspli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data from NSViewController to another NSViewController which is in NSSplitViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157630/pass-data-from-nsviewcontroller-to-another-nsviewcontroller-which-is-in-nssplitv/51159506)